# Squid: restrict proxy_auth (userid) only from selectec sources (src ip)

Tags: ip, squid

I need a way to restrict userid (proxy_auth) only from authentic user pc (src ip).
Because: a userX take lent a userid (login) from another user (boss user) and can access all sites without restrictions.
I need to restrict that userid login can be authenticated only from src ip (from user) that really is the own of this userid login

this can be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you!
I did like you tell, but with some adjusts:

```
acl boss_cnn proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl boss_login proxy_auth bossusername
acl boss_ip src 192.168.0.1
http_access allow boss_cnn boss_login boss_ip
http_access deny boss_cnn boss_login !boss_ip
```

Pay attention in the order of this two lines of http_access.
First I allowed access, but a warning here is allow unnecessary acls (like denied domains).
So in the end, I deny proxy_auth REQUIRED (in acl cnn) with this login when it came from all ip <> ip boss

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following

```
acl local_clients proxy_auth REQUIRED
acl BOSS proxy_auth boss
acl boss_local_ip src 192.168.127.10

http_access allow local_clients BOSS boss_local_ip
http_access deny all
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please refer the case :**

**Using ADS authentication:** just allow proxy auth to specific users and block all other
ads users.

acl Fulltime time M T W H F S A 00:30-23:59

auth_param basic program /usr/bin/ntlm_auth --helper-protocol=squid-2.5-basic

auth_param basic children 5

auth_param basic realm SimpleWall

auth_param basic credentialsttl 2 hours

acl avdhoot proxy_auth avdhoot

acl chetan proxy_auth chetan

acl sharad proxy_auth sharad

acl satish proxy_auth satish

acl sujit proxy_auth sujit

acl Bad_URLs dstdomain -i .youtube.com .fbstatic .fbcdn.net .facebook.com .rediff.com

acl Download_Policies rep_mime_type -i ^video/mp4$ ^video/mpeg$

acl Upload_Policies req_mime_type -i ^image/png$

acl Banned_Patterns url_regex -i .[Ii][Ss][Oo]$

acl Port_Based_Policy port  21

acl Ip_Based_Policy dst 208.64.57.152

deny_info Bad_URLs Bad_URLs

deny_info Download_Policies Download_Policies

deny_info Upload_Policies Upload_Policies

deny_info Banned_Patterns Banned_Patterns

deny_info Port_Based_Policy Port_Based_Policy

deny_info Ip_Based_Policy Ip_Based_Policy

deny_info Fulltime Fulltime

## Last bottom line : deny all other ads users.

acl maped proxy_auth avdhoot chetan sharad satish sujit

acl simplewall proxy_auth REQUIRED

http_access deny simplewall !maped